# Configure Infinispan distributed cache with Jhipster

Tags: jhipster, infinispan

I want to configure Infinispan distributed cache in JHipster.

- How can I configure infinispan distributed cache into JHipter?
- If you have any link for the example so please provide a link that would be easier for me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the instructions [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/using-cache/)?

Comment: Thanks Galder for the response.

Comment: I have tried it but it does not works for me. Do you have any infinispan config-file for JHipster?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? :\ We don't have JHipster specific config files